# Restrict vocabulary on entity_autocomplete form field targeting taxonomy terms

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms, ajax

I'm creating a form with an `entity_autocomplete` field targeting taxonomy terms, and I would like to restrict it to a certain vocabulary. Is there a way to do that with `'#selection_settings'`? I can't find any example.

This is the code I am using.

```
$form['p_cat_ac'] = array(
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#title' => t('Product Category'),
    '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
    '#selection_settings' => [
        'include_anonymous' => FALSE,
    ],
);
```

Answer (score 4):

The vocabulary is the taxonomy term's bundle, so you just have to add a `target_bundles` array to the `#selection_settings` entry. In my case the desired vocabulary ID is 'category'.

```
$form['p_cat_ac'] = array(
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#title' => t('Product Category'),
    '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
    '#selection_settings' => [
        'include_anonymous' => FALSE,
        'target_bundles' => array('category'),
    ],
);
```